# Why does vim incsearch pause when cancelling a search with the <ESC> key?

Tags: vim

In vim, if you `set incsearch` then it will scroll to the next match of your current search term without moving the cursor.  I often use this to read a section of code without moving the cursor there, because I can then hit `<ESC>` and the screen will return back to wherever my cursor was when I started searching.

However, vim has a pause after you hit `<ESC>`, and before it scrolls back to the cursor.  I find this pause very irritating.  What is the purpose behind this pause, and/or is this pause configurable?

Comment: I don't experience this pause: returning to the previous position is instantaneous here at home in GVim 7.3 on Ubuntu and I don't recall ever seeing it at work in MacVim 7.3 (and also in CLI Vim). Could you share your `~/.vimrc`? Also, note that you can use `<C-o>` to jump back.

Comment: @romainl gvim != vim, I have verified this on 3 different systems, one on rhel, two Ubuntu.  Try opening `vim` on a terminal with no .vimrc, then `set incsearch` and try it.

Comment: Yes, tried it in CLI Vim. You are right and @echristopherson's answer seems to be right.

Comment: @echristopherson's answer is pretty much right: Vim has a timeout after pressing Esc.  I usually double-tap Esc (the timeout will still happen after the 2nd one, but I've never noticed that pause because I'm either reading the screen, or I've input a command that doesn't continue an Esc sequence).  You can press Ctrl-C instead of Esc though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running Vim in a terminal. `<Esc>` is the beginning character of many terminal escape sequences, such as cursor movement or <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd> + other keys. If you've defined some alt/meta key mappings somewhere in your config, Vim waits a bit after you hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to make sure the `<Esc>` character isn't the start of a longer sequence.

You'll probably want to check `:help 'timeout'` and adjust settings accordingly. You can set `timeoutlen` to a shorter duration if desired (`ttimeoutlen` is by default set to -1, so it isn't used).

**EDIT**: If you're running Vim in tmux or GNU screen, this probably won't be enough to prevent the pause. If using tmux, try adding `set -s escape-time 0` to your .tmux.conf, [as suggested by Vicent Marti here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/esc-key-causes-a-small-delay-in-terminal-due-to-its-alt-behavior). If using GNU screen, you may have success with adding

```
maptimeout 0
defc1 off
```

to your .screenrc, as [suggested by brian_ruiz here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/gnu-screen-makes-vim-esc-key-slow).

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case.  If you hit ctrl-alt F2, it drops me down to a basic terminal, and then I login as root (no .vimrc), and then start up vim, run `set incsearch` and I can still reproduce it.  In this case there is no terminal emulator to speak of that would eat the `<ESC>`, and nothing has been bound for the Alt or Meta keys.

Comment: The Linux virtual consoles are also terminal emulators, and they use `<Esc>` for meta keys (I think by default; they have on all my systems going back years). But if you haven't mapped anything with an `<Esc>` character, I'm stumped.

Comment: When you say "haven't mapped anything with an `<Esc>` character", do you mean specifically in `vim`, or is there some other place where an `<Esc>` key mapping could be coming in and messing things up, like in a bashrc?

Comment: OK, I guess I was wrong. I also get the pause even when not using a .vimrc. However, it appears that, while the highlighting stays in place for a while, it's actually possible to hit a key and have it acted on immediately. (Strangely, using no .vimrc, if I hit `Esc` after successfully matching some text, the cursor stays where the match was.)